# Passing JSON File to PM2 as a node argument

Tags: node.js, json, linux, pm2

I have a NodeJS app which needs to start the server with the following parameter: `start server.js --config=config.json`. Then in the server.js I use `NodeUtils.getArgs()` and 
`JSON.parse()` to get all the parameters of the config.json file. This works well.

Now, I want to start the server with PM2, but I am not being able.

If I try with `pm2 start server.js --node-args"--config=config.json"` I get a `node: bad option: --config=config.json`. I tried with a lot of options but none of them works.

How can I do it? Thanks

**EDIT: After starting pm2, if it gets an error, you must `pm2 delete all`.**

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your own arguments after `--`, so you can do this:

```js
pm2 start server.js -- -config=config.json
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked after doing pm delete all, I wasn't doing that and the errors were always the same.